# помогите пожалуйста с добавлением класса js

Tags: javascript, jquery

match  ишет слова на сайте затем эти слова помешаются в переменную помогите пожалуйста сделать так чтоб этим найденным словам добавлялся класс на странице

```
let body = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
let jk = JSON.stringify(body); 
let poisk = jk.match(/яблоко/g);
let stoka = poisk.value;
$(stoka).addClass( "myClass" );
```

Comment: Доброе утро. Самому слову класс Вы  вряд ли сможете добавить, а вот тегу, который может оборачивать это слово - да.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
document.documentElement.innerHTML = html.replace(/(яблок)/g, '<span class="red">$1</span>')
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<p>
  Я когда-то умру - мы когда-то всегда умираем, -<br>
  Как бы так угадать, чтоб не сам - чтобы в спину ножом:<br>
  Убиенных щадят, отпевают и балуют раем, -<br>
  Не скажу про живых, а покойников мы бережём.
</p>
<p>
  В грязь ударю лицом, завалюсь покрасивее набок,<br>
  И ударит душа на ворованных клячах в галоп.<br>
  В дивных райских садах наберу бледно-розовых яблок.<br>
  Жаль, сады сторожат и стреляют без промаха в лоб.
</p>
<p>
  Прискакали - гляжу - пред очами не райское что-то:<br>
  Неродящий пустырь и сплошное ничто - беспредел.<br>
  И среди ничего возвышались литые ворота,<br>
  И огромный этап - тысяч пять - на коленях сидел.
</p>
<p>
  Как ржанёт коренной! Я смирил его ласковым словом,<br>
  Да репьи из мочал еле выдрал и гриву заплел.<br>
  Седовласый старик слишком долго возился с засовом -<br>
  И кряхтел и ворчал, и не смог отворить - и ушёл.
</p>
<p>
  И измученный люд не издал ни единого стона,<br>
  Лишь на корточки вдруг с онемевших колен пересел.<br>
  Здесь малина, братва, - нас встречают малиновым звоном!<br>
  Всё вернулось на круг, и распятый над кругом висел.
</p>
<p>
  Всем нам блага подай, да и много ли требовал я благ?<br>
  Мне - чтоб были друзья, да жена - чтобы пала на гроб, -<br>
  Ну а я уж для них наберу бледно-розовых яблок.<br>
  Жаль, сады сторожат и стреляют без промаха в лоб.
</p>
<p>
  Я узнал старика по слезам на щеках его дряблых:<br>
  Это Пётр Святой - он апостол, а я - остолоп.<br>
  Вот и кущи-сады, в коих прорва мороженных яблок.<br>
  Но сады сторожат - и убит я без промаха в лоб.
</p>
<p>
  И погнал я коней прочь от мест этих гнилых и зяблых, -<br>
  Кони просят овсу, но и я закусил удила.<br>
  Вдоль обрыва с кнутом по-над пропастью пазуху яблок<br>
  Для тебя привезу: ты меня и из рая ждала!
</p>
```

Comment: огромное тебе спасибо